# SQL Server : ISNULL not returning a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

I'm trying to write a SQL Statement (in Microsoft SQL Server) that will always return a value of 0 if there is nothing to be found.

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL([ID], 0) AS ID 
FROM 
    ecdb.dbo.tbl_units 
WHERE 
    ([GENESYS_NAME] = 'EDRD');
```

The statement above returns an empty value (nothing), see screenshot.

Now if I enter a true statement that returns a value  (replace 'EDRD' with 'ERD'), it returns a value of 1, which is correct.

The reason why I need it to return a value of zero is that I plan to use this statement as a sub query of a master statement where I need the ID (not the GENESYS_NAME) and my table has set aside 0 to be an unknown entry.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: You are mistaken. Your query returns no rows. Therefore, there is no NULL value on which ISNULL can operate. If you plan to use it as a subquery, you simply wrap the subquery in ISNULL. The problem with your approach is that you focus on the wrong part - show a complete query that more closely resembles your actual goal to get better suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting only 1 row as result you can use an aggregate function like `MAX()`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX([ID]), 0) AS ID 
FROM ecdb.dbo.tbl_units 
WHERE ([GENESYS_NAME]='EDRD');
```

Another way to do it, which will work also if you expect more than 1 rows in the results is with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT [ID]
FROM ecdb.dbo.tbl_units 
WHERE ([GENESYS_NAME]='EDRD')
UNION ALL
SELECT 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM ecdb.dbo.tbl_units 
  WHERE ([GENESYS_NAME]='EDRD') 
)
```

Comment: Interesting. So your code returned `NULL` but when I wrap it is an ISNULL, then it actually returns a 0, which is what I need.

Comment: Correct. MAX(id) should be wrapped inside is null.

Comment: the trick is that with the aggregate function, we will get a row back, consider return from `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`  when no rows satisfy the conditions, we get a row back with zero.  Contrast this with `SELECT id FROM ...` when no rows satisfy the conditions, we get an empty resultset, zero rows returned.

Comment: @spencer7593 this is the requirement: to get 1 row.